# Segmentation fault in recursive function

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault

I recently read about memoization for the first time(I'm a noob) and I wanted to try and make a fibonacci function that uses memoization. This is what I've tried, but anything over 1 just gives me a segmentation fault. Any help is appreciated!

```
unsigned int fibonacci( unsigned int n )
{
    vector<unsigned int> fibvector;
    if ( n <= 1 )
        return n;
    if ( fibvector.size() >= n )
        return fibvector[n];
    unsigned int add = fibonacci( n-1 ) + fibonacci( n-2 );
    fibvector[n] = add;
    return add;
}
```

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for the vector but you're using `[n]` to access its contents.

Comment: How do I do this manually? I thought the vector would allocate the memory itself?

Comment: It does, but only when you do something like `push_back(n)`. When you use `[n]`, it returns a reference to a memory address that it hasn't allocated space for internally. Only after you use `push_back` can you do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
vector<unsigned int> fibvector;
```

is a local variable. each time you call `fibonacci(n)` there will be a new vector created, with no elements. You can fix it by making it static.

```
static vector<unsigned int> fibvector(MAXELEMENTS);
```

MAXELEMENTS is used for initialization purposes. And in this case, you need to test using

```
if(fibvector[n] != 0) return fibvector[n];
```

Edit: ***If you want to not require a fixed amount of elements*** you can use the following

```
unsigned int fibonacci( unsigned int n )
{
    static vector<unsigned int> fibvector;
    unsigned int fib;

    if ( fibvector.size() > n )
        return fibvector[n];
    if(n <=1){
       fib = n;
    }
    else{
       unsigned int v2 = fibonacci( n-2 );
       unsigned int v1 = fibonacci( n-1 );
       fib = v2 + v1;
    }
    fibvector.push_back(fib);
    return fib;
}
```

The idea is that the recursion method of fibonacci(n) would first compute fibonacci(0), fibonacci(1), fibonacci(2) till fibonacci(n). Which means it will compute following the natural order of n, and the push_back will accurately follow this ordering.

Comment: I'd make this vector a reference parameter to the function rather declaring it static.

Comment: Thanks a lot! But do you have to set the maxelements in the beginning? I would like it to ideally have no max elements.

Comment: @Arnstein: Yes, you may, but then you have to make sure to regrow it whenever it is too small. I'd recommend making the vector a reference parameter, as g-makulik suggests. You can even overload your function in order to provide a clean interface (that is, `fibonacci(n)`, would call `fibonacci(n,vector<unsigned int>(n))`).

Comment: @UmNyobe This code give me the wrong numbers.{
    static vector<unsigned int> fibvector;
    unsigned int add = 1;
    if ( n <= 1 )
        return n;
    if ( fibvector.size() > n )
        return fibvector[n];
    if ( n > 1 )
    {
        unsigned int v1 = fibonacci( n-2 );
        unsigned int v2 = fibonacci( n-1 );
        add = v2+v1;
    }
    fibvector.push_back( add );
    return add;
}

Comment: `if ( n <= 1 ) return n; ` well this is incorrect Fibonnaci(0)=1, and i didnt mention that. It was one of the bug in your original post. I tested the correctness of the function i posted.

Comment: @Umnyobe With Fibonacci(0), n would be 0, and return 0, right? Everything works right, up until Fibonacci(6), where I get 11, when it should be 8.

Comment: you are correct, I made a mistake with the initial values, see edit (thanks for seeing it :D)

Comment: @UmNyobe Thanks, ofcourse I should have added and not just returned the value if it's less than or equal to 1! It works now, at least up to 40. Between 40 and 50 it gives the wrong value, so I will have to check that out. I will also make a class out of it :) Thanks for helping!

Comment: beware of arithmetic overflow :D!!!!! fibonacci(42) > 2^32. use long long instead to get some little oxygen.

Comment: @UmNyobe I tried with long now, but 43 becomes the value for 44, 44 is the value it should be, and everything after that is obviously messed up!

Comment: this is another issue : **number overflow**. the most appropriate resolution is to use a ***big integer*** library. ps: search on SO and online, plenty of information.

Answer (score 0):

Others have commented on your lack of `push_backs` for your vector.  I'll add that your vector is purely local to one call of your function--it has no scope up and down the recursive call stack so it won't function as you anticipated.  Instead, you need to make the vector `static`, or better yet pass it by reference to each recursive call.  Better still would be to make this a class.

Comment: My goal is to make it a class, I just wanted to try it out in a simple function first!